# Static std::unique_ptr declared in .cpp but also called and used in respective .h file

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, static, unique-ptr

I have a `static std::unique_ptr map` that I declared in a getter in `X.cpp` and use to access the `map` in both `X.cpp` and `X.h`:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<std::map<...>>& getMap() {
    static std::unique_ptr<std::map<...>> xMap;
    return xMap;
}
```

However, it seems I'm getting a read access violation in `X.h` saying that the pointer is null.

Would the best option be to move the getter into the `X.h` file?

Comment: You have a `static` pointer but never set it to anything. It should be `static auto xMap = std::make_unique<std::map<...>>();`. However, since your object is `static` you should probably just have `static std::map<...> xMap;` and return a `std::map<...> &` instead. Either way, it is unlikely you want to return a `unique_ptr` reference like this. Anyone could `.reset()` it.

Comment: That fixed it - thanks! In regards to the last part of you answer, I considered passing it by 'const reference', but realized I needed to change the contents of the 'std::unique_ptr' when I use the getter function. I'm honestly not sure why the previous code owners used a getter function here - I'm thinking a better bet would be to just have 'xMap' as a member variable 'std::unique_ptr' and not one accessed by getter. The only other thing I'm also confused about is why it's 'static' (it was originally a 'static std::map', but I changed it to a 'static std::unique_ptr<std::map>>' to fix a bug).

Comment: One reason for using a `static` member function instead of a `static` data member is to avoid problems related to initialization order. A local `static` variable is initialized on first use, so by using a member functions you have more control over that. `static` data members in different translation units (.cpp files) are initialized in an unspecified order which in some cases can be problematic if a `static` data member's initialization depends on another from another translation unit. This is the "Meyers' Singleton" pattern.

Comment: If a `unique_ptr` is actually required here (it almost certainly is not) then you can still return a reference by returning `*xMap` instead. I can't imagine a scenario where returning a non-const `unique_ptr` to a singleton is the correct solution. If it looks like it fixes a bug, then this is likely just hiding a more significant underlying bug. If it *is* the correct solution, I would be curious to learn more about the problem it fixes.

Comment: I guess we thought a `std::unique_ptr` would help fix a destruction order bug on iOS. This occurred on the destruction of an outer static object, which internally referred to the `static xMap`. We were thinking `xMap` or the mutex used before accessing `xMap` with `getMap()` were dead, and thought a check on whether `xMap` was alive before use and moving on otherwise would help us with that bug.

Comment: Sounds like a [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) problem.